# Code generation unavailable in Clion project

Tags: c++, clion

I have a project in Clion, with some sources. When I create a class, and insert, say a member variable, I am supposed to be able to let clion generate, among others setters/getters.
Instead, right-click on "Generate", or from "Code->Generate..." I can only see the option to generate "Copyright".

Minimal example to reproduce the problem:

- create an empty directory
- copy inside a test source, say `test.cpp`:

  struct A {
  int x;
  };
- open clion with `clion .` in the directory
- click on "Trust" project.
- double click on `test.cpp` and try to right-click "Generate"

If this is relevant, the actual project does *not* have a CMakeList, because the compile chain is based on the old GNU Make, with standard Makefile.
Even if a Makefile is created with compilation tasks for `test.cpp`, still it is not possible to use the automatic generation of code.